# Advice for running an MQTT server

Tags: push-notification, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to run Mosquitto MQTT broker on my server. 
And I want to have for example 10 million users/clients connected.
I want to know a few things first:

1. Can Mosquitto handle 10 million alive connections?
2. If I want to have i.e. 8 Topics and categories for each client, can the broker handle 80 million topics?!
3. If 100 thousand clients publish a message at the same time, what happens? can the broker handle it?
4. If the answer to all above is yes, then what hardware specifications is needed for that to run without problem under Windows Server 2008 R2?(CPU,RAM,HDD,...)
5. Is there any better broker than Mosquitto?(in performance, supporting user/pass, supporting ssl/tls)
6. If it's not possible at all, then how are big companies/apps like Whatsapp/Viber/Wechat/others handling push notifications for their apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not at the moment, and on Windows it is currently limited to 1000 clients.
2. Probably, but it will most likely depend on the arrangement of these topics.
3. "Can the broker handle it?" - it depends what you mean by handle it. There will definitely be a good chunk of latency added.
4. As above, Windows currently only supports 1000 clients.
5. There are plenty of vendors who will sell you a solution.
6. I imagine that the lightweight protocols are mostly restricted to the edge of their network, with other messaging used internally, and lots of servers.

Comment: thanks, and I didn't understand the number 6, I didn't mean messaging, I meant Push Notifications.

Comment: Well ultimately push notifications are messaging.

Comment: I finally realized that I should not use MQTT at all. I switched to AMQP. thanks.